# How to fetch a row using mysqli query?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to fetch a row from my mysql DB using mysqli query.

**PHP**

```
$_SESSION['orderID'] = "632";
$orID = $_SESSION['orderID'];
$sql = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM order_list WHERE order_id = ? ');
$sql->bind_param('s',$orID);
$sql->execute();
while($row = $sql->fetch()) 
{
   $productid = $row[0];
   $name = $row[1];
   echo $price = $row[2];

}
```

give no error in console and no result,

I have been trying to check the answers on stack overflow, I also googled it but all the suggestions gives me the same error.

I am pretty new with mysqli, your help will be highly appreciated

Comment: which particular answers did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_array` is a `mysqli_result` method not a `mysqli_stmt` one

You could use `->fetch()` upon a `mysqli_stmt`

So basically your code could change that way

```
while($sql->fetch()) {
 //do something
}
```

but you need to call `bind_result()` before looping (otherwise you can't access returned values)